Is the oil level here too high that it needs to be drained or can I leave it?

Honda civic coupe vti 1999.
Just did an engine oil change however the oil is above max.  The oil in the picture is not very clear so I have put a red arrow to show the level.
Is this high enough that it might cause performance issues or damage or is it ok to just leave it and it will burn off over time!
Thanks

Yes, I agree with Paulster2.  It looks like about an extra half liter of oil.  Excess oil also occupies more space in the crankcase, in turn creating an excess pressure that forces oil in places it does not belong.  It could damage the engine (e.g., seals), especially at higher rpm.
Since you just had the oil serviced, you have a right to return to the shop and insist that the excess oil be drained.  I recently had the same problem and the shop did not want to drain the oil.  When they did remove the drain plug (as Paulster2 describes), they lost about 2-3 liters.  The shop did not want to pay for the missing oil, so they charged me more money.  I never returned to that shop again.
Alternatively, auto parts stores often sell handheld pumps that can remove oil through the dipstick.  I have used them with success.  You might want to give it a try.  It's obviously a hassle . . . welcome to car ownership!

Anything over full is not good. If this is the level after the engine was ran, then yes, I'd drain some out of it. If it wasn't after you have already ran it, then run it, give the oil a chance to settle (5 mins) and check it again by pulling the dipstick, wipe, quick stab, pull, and check again.
The reason you don't want too much oil is, if the crankshaft comes in contact with the oil in the sump, it aerates it, causing the engine to lose oil pressure. This can cause premature wear in the engine.
You can easily drain the excess oil by pulling the pan plug and draining off a little into an oil drain pan. A quick second's worth of drain, then seal it back up. Once the plug is back in, check the oil level. Do this as much as you need to until you have the correct level showing on the dipstick.
